# Make aspect ratios of Plot3D axis be 1 (display as cube)

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I'm trying to configure 3D plot to be displayed as a perfect cube.

Setting `AspectRatio -> 1` like you would do in a reqular `Plot` to make image rectangular does not seem to work for 3D case:

```
Plot3D[{1/(x^2 + y^2)}, {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 4}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 4}, {0, 8}}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> {{LightBlue, Opacity[0.5]}}, 
  Lighting -> {{"Ambient", LightBlue}}, ClippingStyle -> None, 
  BoundaryStyle -> {Blue}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}
]
```

Which setting should I use and how?

[image]

Comment: You are probably looking for [`BoxRatios`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoxRatios.html). Try removing your `AspectRatio` option, and replacing it with `BoxRatios -> Automatic`, which should adjust the shape of the graphics box to correspond to the actual coordinate values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Replace `AspectRatio` with [`BoxRatios`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoxRatios.html)

```
p1 = Plot3D[{1/(x^2 + y^2)}, {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 4}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 4}, {0, 8}}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
   Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> {{LightBlue, Opacity[0.5]}}, 
   Lighting -> {{"Ambient", LightBlue}}, ClippingStyle -> None, 
   BoundaryStyle -> {Blue}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}];
p2 = Plot3D[{1/(x^2 + y^2)}, {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 4}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 4}, {0, 8}}, BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
   Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> {{LightBlue, Opacity[0.5]}}, 
   Lighting -> {{"Ambient", LightBlue}}, ClippingStyle -> None, 
   BoundaryStyle -> {Blue}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}];
GraphicsRow[{p1, p2}, ImageSize -> {800, Automatic}]
```

[image]

Comment: Young, at first I though that `BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}` was not what the OP wanted (I thought they wanted the length of each axis to be proportional to the range of the variables represented), but on second reading of their question, you might be right! I wonder, would you consider perhaps including the output with `BoxRatios -> Automatic` as well, so both options are presented?

Comment: @MarcoB Sure. Good idea.